# Multi-line chart with seaborn tsplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create a smoothed line chart using matplotlib and seaborn.

This is my dataframe `df`:

```
hour    direction    hourly_avg_count
0       1            20
1       1            22
2       1            21
3       1            21
..      ...          ...
24      1            15
0       2            24
1       2            28
...     ...          ...
```

The line chart should contain two lines, one for `direction` equal to 1, another for `direction` equal to 2. The X axis is `hour` and Y axis is `hourly_avg_count`.

I tried this, but I cannot see the lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.tsplot(df, time='hour', condition='direction', value='hourly_avg_count')
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `tsplot` here, pandas plotting methods will suffice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `tsplot` is a bit strange or at least strangly documented. If a dataframe is supplied to it, it assumes that there must be a `unit` and a `time` column present, as it internally pivots about those two. To use `tsplot` to plot several time series you would therefore need to supply an argument to `unit` as well; this can be the same as `condition`.

```
sns.tsplot(df, time='hour', unit = "direction", 
               condition='direction', value='hourly_avg_count')
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hour, direction = np.meshgrid(np.arange(24), np.arange(1,3))
df = pd.DataFrame({"hour": hour.flatten(), "direction": direction.flatten()})
df["hourly_avg_count"] = np.random.randint(14,30, size=len(df))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.tsplot(df, time='hour', unit = "direction", 
               condition='direction', value='hourly_avg_count')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Also worth noting that [tsplot is deprecated](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017) as of seaborn version 0.8. It might thus be worth to use some other way to plot the data anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a dummy unit column. The first parts is to create some synthetic data, so please ignore.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"hour":range(24),
"direction":1,
"hourly_avg_count": np.random.randint(25,28,size=24)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
"hour":range(24),
"direction":2,
"hourly_avg_count": np.random.randint(25,28,size=24)})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
df['unit'] = 'subject'

plt.figure()
sns.tsplot(data=df, time='hour', condition='direction',
unit='unit', value='hourly_avg_count')
```

[image]