# Replacement for deprecated tsplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a time-series with uniform samples save to a numpy array and I'd like to plot their mean value with a bootstrapped confidence interval. Typically, I've used `tsplot` from Seaborn to accomplish this. However, this is now [being deprecated](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-1-september-2017). What am I supposed to use a replacement?

Here is an example usage below adapted from the Seaborn documentation:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(10, 31) + np.random.randn(10, 1)
sns.tsplot(data)
```

**Note:** this is similar to questions "[Seaborn tsplot error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831596/seaborn-tsplot-error)" and "[Multi-line chart with seaborn tsplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327767/multi-line-chart-with-seaborn-tsplot/45329593#45329593)". However, in my case, I actually need the confidence interval functionality of Seaborn and thus cannot simply use Matplotlib without some awkward coding.

Comment: @BradSolomon because it's an awkward interface for plotting Pandas time-series data and has caused much confusion in the past

Comment: Indeed, I think the number of people trying to use tsplot and ending up totally confused is much higher than the number of people actually using it.

Comment: I use tsplot regularly... I sure hope they replace it rather than just nuking it. Maybe they can hide it from people and leave it there...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The example `tsplot` from the question can easily be replicated using matplotlib.

#### Using standard deviation as error estimate

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(10, 31) + np.random.randn(10, 1)


fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
ax = sns.tsplot(data=data,ax=ax, ci="sd")

def tsplot(ax, data,**kw):
    x = np.arange(data.shape[1])
    est = np.mean(data, axis=0)
    sd = np.std(data, axis=0)
    cis = (est - sd, est + sd)
    ax.fill_between(x,cis[0],cis[1],alpha=0.2, **kw)
    ax.plot(x,est,**kw)
    ax.margins(x=0)

tsplot(ax2, data)

ax.set_title("sns.tsplot")
ax2.set_title("custom tsplot")

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using bootstrapping for error estimate

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(10, 31) + np.random.randn(10, 1)


fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
ax = sns.tsplot(data=data,ax=ax)

def bootstrap(data, n_boot=10000, ci=68):
    boot_dist = []
    for i in range(int(n_boot)):
        resampler = np.random.randint(0, data.shape[0], data.shape[0])
        sample = data.take(resampler, axis=0)
        boot_dist.append(np.mean(sample, axis=0))
    b = np.array(boot_dist)
    s1 = np.apply_along_axis(stats.scoreatpercentile, 0, b, 50.-ci/2.)
    s2 = np.apply_along_axis(stats.scoreatpercentile, 0, b, 50.+ci/2.)
    return (s1,s2)
    
def tsplotboot(ax, data,**kw):
    x = np.arange(data.shape[1])
    est = np.mean(data, axis=0)
    cis = bootstrap(data)
    ax.fill_between(x,cis[0],cis[1],alpha=0.2, **kw)
    ax.plot(x,est,**kw)
    ax.margins(x=0)

tsplotboot(ax2, data)

ax.set_title("sns.tsplot")
ax2.set_title("custom tsplot")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

I guess the reason this is deprecated is exactly that the use of this function is rather limited and in most cases you are better off just plotting the data you want to plot directly.

Answer (score 13):

The replacement for `tsplot` called [`lineplot`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1285) was introduced in  version `0.9.0`. It doesn't support Numpy-like "[wide-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data)" data, thus the data has to be transformed using Pandas.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(10, 31) + np.random.randn(10, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data).melt()
sns.lineplot(x="variable", y="value", data=df)
```

Or using the new `seaborn.objects`:

```py
(
    so.Plot(pd.DataFrame(data).melt(), x="variable", y="value")
    .add(so.Line(), so.Agg()).add(so.Band(), so.Est())
)
```