# seaborn tsplot only showing one line

Tags: time-series, seaborn

I'm trying to do a time series plot using seaborn on the following data:

```
      infant   shannon   DOL  subject
0     N1_003  0.262301  11.0        0
1     N1_003  0.715419  13.0        0
1161  S2_018  1.085983  22.0        0
1162  S2_018  1.126659  23.0        0
```

But for some reason the line for infant S2_018 only show up using the following code?

```
def plot_ts(db):
    db=db[['infant', 'shannon', 'DOL']]
    db=db.drop_duplicates()
    db=db.dropna()
    db['subject'] = 0

    sns.tsplot(time='DOL', # Horizontal axis
           value='shannon', # Vertical axis
           data=db, # Data source
           unit='subject',
           condition="infant",
           interpolate=True,
           legend=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plot ranges from 22 to 23 on the x axis, the data of the `N1_003` are however 11 and 13. So you just need to get the correct limits of the plot. To this end, just add

```
plt.autoscale()
```

at the end of your function.

[image]

Note however that `tsplot` is not really the first choice for plotting simple things like the dataframe from the question. Also, as of version version 0.8 of seaborn, `tsplot` [is deprecated](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581672/replacement-for-deprecated-tsplot) for when it's useful.

Here just consider a normal pandas plot,

```
for n, infant in db.groupby("infant"):
    infant.plot(x="DOL", y="shannon", ax=plt.gca(), label=n);
```