# Simple tsplot for timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have below dataframe:

```
    Date    group   count
0   2015-01-12 Category1    27
1   2015-01-19 Category1    2
2   2015-01-26 Category1    31
3   2015-02-02 Category1    20
4   2015-02-09 Category1    24
5   2015-02-16 Category1    16
6   2015-02-23 Category1    18
7   2015-03-02 Category1    15
8   2015-03-09 Category1    29
9   2015-03-16 Category1    6
10  2015-03-23 Category1    19
11  2015-03-30 Category1    27
12  2015-04-06 Category1    6
13  2015-04-07 Category1    7
14  2015-04-13 Category1    25
15  2015-04-20 Category1    9
```

I want to plot a simple timeseries **using seaborn**. Just a line chart of count on the Y-Axis, with Date on the X-axis something like this just for example: [image]

I thought it would be as simple as: `sns.tsplot(data=df, time=df['Date'], value=df['count'])` or `sns.tsplot(data=df, time='Date', value='count')` and following the [`tsplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html) documentation I can't quite get this simple line of code. The datatypes seem fine, but what am i missing here?:

```
#df.dtypes
Date     datetime64[ns]
group            object
count             int64
```

Side note, does anyone know why `tsplot()` is being [deprecated](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017) for? (beyond the vague definition in the docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `tsplot` is deprecated because people tend to think it would be useful for plotting timeseries - which isn't the case. Of course you may use it, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327767/multi-line-chart-with-seaborn-tsplot), but I would recommend simply plotting the data as a line plot:

```
ax = df.plot(x="Date", y="count")
ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Comment: I also came to the conclusion of using `matplotlib` instead. I struggled with this for an hour or so with `tnsplot`. Is there any way to use `tnsplot` here - or no? (hence the deprecation)

Comment: Well, I guess there are ways to make an strawberry pie taste like an apple pie, but why would you do that - apples are cheaper, so just use apples. Unless you give me a clear motivation why using `tsplot` is desirable over just plotting the dataframe with `plot`, I don't think it's even worth spending any effort in that direction.

Comment: E.g. one such motivation was given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581672/replacement-for-deprecated-tsplot), where the user wanted to have confidence intervals.

Comment: Haha I love this comment and agree. The "clear motivation" is purely to answer this question on SO if it's possible with `tsplot`. I guess this "answers" my question with a `no - this way is better`

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.tsplot(data=pd.Series([10,15,20,15,20,25,20,25,30,35,30,35,40,45]), color="b")
```

[image]

However note that the answer of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is more appropriate

Comment: this does not return the expected output. What does it look like on your end?