# Second y-axis time series

Tags: python, seaborn

Using the data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date" : ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04"],
    "column1" : [555,525,532,585],
    "column2" : [50,48,49,51]
})
```

one can plot with `seaborn` say `column1` with `sns.tsplot(data=df.column1, color="g")`.

How can we plot both time series with two y-axis in seaborn ?

Comment: I would recommend not to use `tsplot` for a normal timeseries. See e.g. yesterday's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578622/simple-tsplot-for-timeseries).

Comment: Just as it says, people think they should use tsplot for plotting their time-dependend data using a `tsplot`, but it has never actually been designed for that purpose.

Comment: Also see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327767/multi-line-chart-with-seaborn-tsplot#comment77622210_45327767) by the author of seaborn.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I would recommend using a normal line plot. You can get a twin axes via `ax.twinx()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04"],
                   "column1": [555,525,532,585], 
                   "column2": [50,48,49,51]})

ax = df.plot(x="date", y="column1", legend=False)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.plot(x="date", y="column2", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
ax.figure.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but 90% of the time when someone wants to "use seaborn" they just don't realize that seaborn is just a nice but incomplete interface to matplotlib and that the way pandas wraps things might be equally suitable. Also note that at the time this answer was written, seaborn did not have the `lineplot` function.

Answer (score 120):

As `seaborn` is built on the top of `matplotlib`, you can use its power:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.lineplot(data=df.column1, color="g")
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=df.column2, color="b", ax=ax2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following code, based on @Andrey Sobolev's solution, but which will also generate a complete legend.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
    
g = sb.lineplot(data=df.column1, color="g")
sb.lineplot(data=df.column2, color="b", ax=g.axes.twinx())
g.legend(handles=[Line2D([], [], marker='_', color="g", label='column1'), Line2D([], [], marker='_', color="b", label='column2')])
```

[image: output]