# Seaborn barplot with two y-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

considering the following pandas DataFrame:

```
          labels  values_a  values_b  values_x  values_y
  0       date1      1         3        150       170
  1       date2      2         6        200       180
```

It is easy to plot this with Seaborn (see example code below). However, due to the big difference between values_a/values_b and values_x/values_y, the bars for values_a and values_b are not easily visible (actually, the dataset given above is just a sample and in my real dataset the difference is even bigger). Therefore, I would like to use two y-axis, i.e., one y-axis for values_a/values_b and one for values_x/values_y. I tried to use plt.twinx() to get a second axis but unfortunately, the plot shows only two bars for values_x and values_y, even though there are at least two y-axis with the right scaling. :) Do you have an idea how to fix that and get four bars for each label whereas the values_a/values_b bars relate to the left y-axis and the values_x/values_y bars relate to the right y-axis?

Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

columns = ["labels", "values_a", "values_b", "values_x", "values_y"]
test_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records([("date1", 1, 3, 150, 170),\
                                       ("date2", 2, 6, 200, 180)],\
                                       columns=columns)

# working example but with unreadable values_a and values_b
test_data_melted = pd.melt(test_data, id_vars=columns[0],\
                           var_name="source", value_name="value_numbers")
g = sns.barplot(x=columns[0], y="value_numbers", hue="source",\
                data=test_data_melted)
plt.show()

# values_a and values_b are not displayed
values1_melted = pd.melt(test_data, id_vars=columns[0],\
                         value_vars=["values_a", "values_b"],\
                         var_name="source1", value_name="value_numbers1")
values2_melted = pd.melt(test_data, id_vars=columns[0],\
                         value_vars=["values_x", "values_y"],\
                         var_name="source2", value_name="value_numbers2")
g1 = sns.barplot(x=columns[0], y="value_numbers1", hue="source1",\
                 data=values1_melted)
ax2 = plt.twinx()
g2 = sns.barplot(x=columns[0], y="value_numbers2", hue="source2",\
                 data=values2_melted, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Working example]
[image: values_a/values_b missing]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591650/second-y-axis-time-series-seaborn

Comment: Tried that solution but it didn't work for me so that I supposed it is different for barplots.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is probably best suited for multiple sub-plots, but if you are truly set on a single plot, you can scale the data before plotting, create another axis and then modify the tick values.

#### Sample Data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

columns = ["labels", "values_a", "values_b", "values_x", "values_y"]
test_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records([("date1", 1, 3, 150, 170),\
                                       ("date2", 2, 6, 200, 180)],\
                                       columns=columns)

test_data_melted = pd.melt(test_data, id_vars=columns[0],\
                           var_name="source", value_name="value_numbers")
```

#### Code:

```
# Scale the data, just a simple example of how you might determine the scaling
mask = test_data_melted.source.isin(['values_a', 'values_b'])
scale = int(test_data_melted[~mask].value_numbers.mean()
            /test_data_melted[mask].value_numbers.mean())
test_data_melted.loc[mask, 'value_numbers'] = test_data_melted.loc[mask, 'value_numbers']*scale

# Plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
g = sns.barplot(x=columns[0], y="value_numbers", hue="source",\
                data=test_data_melted, ax=ax1)

# Create a second y-axis with the scaled ticks
ax1.set_ylabel('X and Y')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Ensure ticks occur at the same positions, then modify labels
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.set_yticklabels(np.round(ax1.get_yticks()/scale,1))
ax2.set_ylabel('A and B')

plt.show()
```

[image]