# seaborn plot with two y axis

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter

I have some data and need to generate a plot like this image, I just wonder how to do this using python seaborn scatter plot?
Thanks, heaps!
example:

[image]

Comment: Here are the same questions as you and the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591650/second-y-axis-time-series-seaborn).

Comment: use `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` then plot the second dataset on `ax2`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal example using [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(size=10),
                    'y1': np.random.random(size=10),
                   })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(size=10),
                    'y2': np.random.random(size=10)*100,
                   })
ax1 = plt.subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.scatterplot(data=df1, x='x', y='y1', ax=ax1)
sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x='x', y='y2', color='r', ax=ax2)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
```

output:

[image: twinx seaborn scatterplot]